# What is the difference between apoptosis caused by the release of enzymes from the electron transport chain vs that from the lysosome?

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria, eukaryotic-cells, organelle

I know that the mitochondria is responsible for regulating apoptosis via release of enzymes from the electron transport chain. I believe that the release of hydrolytic enzymes from a lysosome is how apoptosis occurs due to lysosomes. According to my book, the difference is that in the case of lysosomes, it leads directly to degradation. I’m just wondering how the process of apoptosis differs in each case.

Here is some info for context:
“The mitochondria are also capable of killing the cell by release of enzymes from the electron transport chain. This kickstarts a process known as apoptosis”

“Lysosomes are membrane-bound structures containing hydrolytic enzymes that are capable of breaking down many different substrates including substances ingested by endocytosis and cellular waste products... (endosomes are talked about)... The lysosomal membrane sequesters these enzymes to prevent damage to the cell. The release of these enzymes can occur in a process known as autolysis. Like mitochondria, when lysosomes released their hydrolytic enzymes, it results in apoptosis. **In this case, the released enzymes directly lead to the degradation of cellular components**

The reason I’m unsure if the release of hydrolytic enzymes is involved in apoptosis is because when it says “the lysosomal membrane sequesters these enzymes”, the previous text talked about how endosomes package and transport materials so I wasn’t sure if the enzymes are those materials or if it was referencing the hydrolytic enzymes.

TL;DR version: these are my two questions:

1. Is the release of hydrolytic enzymes from lysosomes responsible for apoptosis?
2. What is the difference between the processes mitochondrial and lysosomal apoptosis?